# Error in Implementing PrimeFaces extensions

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I am new to primefaces and trying to implement the primefaces extensions.
As per the guide I have added the following jars to my buildpath:
1) commons-lang3-3.1.jar
2) gson-2.3.1.jar
3) primefaces-5.0.jar
4) primefaces-5.0-sources.jar
5) primefaces-extensions-3.2.0.jar

and I  have created an xhtml and managed bean as suggested here:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/timeline/basic.jsf

Following is the error log for the same:

```
Jun 25, 2015 4:07:05 PM com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl log
1100: org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.resolveWidgetVar(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;Lorg/primefaces/component/api/Widget;)Ljava/lang/String;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.resolveWidgetVar(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;Lorg/primefaces/component/api/Widget;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.primefaces.extensions.component.timeline.Timeline.resolveWidgetVar(Timeline.java:713)
    at org.primefaces.extensions.component.timeline.TimelineTagHandler.onComponentPopulated(TimelineTagHandler.java:58)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:218)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:203)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:161)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:990)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.tcs.its.permission.filter.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:58)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You are new to PF... Why do you start with the latest extensions and an old 'core'?

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by using a wrong combination of PF and PFE... With PF5, you can only use PFE 2.0/2.1.Searching in google for the error in the stacktrace would have told you so

**See also**

- https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/wiki/Release-Notes

Comment: Did this answer help? Please accept it then, or state what did not work

Comment: I got the same problem today. Had to switch to PF 5.2 to solve. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces.extensions/primefaces-extensions/3.1.0